# Sending data of html form to another form at same page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have read that its not possible to load data to html form with code.It has to be user entered.if thats not right my question is ı have 2 bootstrap modals on MVC project.When user enters image on first modal (form1).First modal hides and second modal appears.What ı want is its pre loaded with form1s image data.

If thats impossible than is it possible to use data entered form1 from first modal and call it on modal2?

Form1

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group files color">
        @Html.TextBox("files", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file", @id = "files", })
    </div>
}
```

Form2

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Açıklayıcı Başlık</label>
        @Html.TextBox("fileload", null, new { @type = "file", @id = "fileload" })
        @Html.TextArea("text", null, new { @type = "file", @id = "text", @class = "form-control", @rows = "3", @placeholder = "Yayını açıklayan bir yazı yaz" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-primary" value="Yükle" />
}
```

Comment: Disregarding the first sentence of your question (unless further clarified), and since you tagged [`jquery`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: if its possible to preload the form ı assume we use jquery or something?